# is the speed is only problem for training tensorflow model with cpu

Tags: tensorflow

I am training to train tensorflow with cpu,it is slow, i have no problem with this but my question is

> "will my mdel be trained as like gpu, is the only difference between
>   cpu and gpu in deep learning is speed?

my train code

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

I am using windows 10

Comment: What do you mean with "as like gpu"? The final result may vary slightly because the training process is nondeterministic (you shuffle your input data, right?). This is independent of where you train.

Comment: If what you want to know is whether the results of the operations will differ, then no, the computation will be the same on CPU or GPU. _Essentially_. What I mean is, GPU and CPU implementations do not use the same code, so it is possible to see slight differences due to precision limits. But, to be fair, even [running the same graph twice on a GPU could produce slightly different results](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3103). But other than that, yes, the only real difference is speed.

Comment: thanks "GPhilo" and "jdehesa" for replying

so in general if iam training images on cpu will trained as gpu but in more time, right?